Go GDAL bindings: CPLErr has no field or method 'Err' when using lukeroth/gdal with TileDB-Go
I have installed GDAL and TileDB, along with all necessary dependencies, on my system. However, when I try to run my Go project that uses the lukeroth/gdal and TileDB-Go bindings, I encounter the following error:
../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/lukeroth/gdal@v0.0.0-20240301124940-d4ff2229365e/algorithms.go:325:3: 
CPLErr(func() _Ctype_CPLErr {…}()).Err undefined (type CPLErr has no field or method Err)

It seems that the CPLErr type in the GDAL Go bindings does not have an Err field or method. I'm unsure if this is a version mismatch between the GDAL library and the Go bindings, or if there's another issue causing this error.
In addition, I also receive warnings regarding deprecated functions when using TileDB-Go:
warning: 'tiledb_array_schema_dump' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

Versions:
GDAL 3.8.4, released 2024/02/08
Libtiledb.so.2.27
github.com/lukeroth/gdal v0.0.0-20240301124940-d4ff2229365e
github.com/TileDB-Inc/TileDB-Go v0.32.0


That just looks like incorrect code, the type has no Err() method. There seems to be no tagged releases or even much for tests, maybe checkout a earlier version? (or try to patch the code locally, maybe that was a typo and no one has tried to build it since)

See https://github.com/lukeroth/gdal/pull/102 for solution.
You can just modify the local "algorithms.go" by yourself.
    return CPLErr(C.GDALContourGenerate(
    src.cval,
    C.double(interval),
    C.double(base),
    C.int(len(fixedLevels)),
    fixedLevels_p,
    C.int(useNoDataValue),
    C.double(noDataValue),
    unsafe.Pointer(layer.cval),
    C.int(idFieldIndex),
    C.int(elevationFieldIndex),
    C.goGDALProgressFuncProxyB(),
    unsafe.Pointer(arg),
)).Err()

to
    cErr := C.GDALContourGenerate(
    src.cval,
    C.double(interval),
    C.double(base),
    C.int(len(fixedLevels)),
    fixedLevels_p,
    C.int(useNoDataValue),
    C.double(noDataValue),
    unsafe.Pointer(layer.cval),
    C.int(idFieldIndex),
    C.int(elevationFieldIndex),
    C.goGDALProgressFuncProxyB(),
    unsafe.Pointer(arg),
)
return CPLErrContainer{ErrVal: cErr}.Err()

